# Creating & Assigning a css class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```js
//Dynamically getting the windows width
var windowwidth = $(window).width() - 50;

//dynamically assigning the windowwidth value to the class(dynamically)
$(window).load(function () {
    $('.cntnt').css('width', windowwidth + 'px');
})


$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.wrapper-content').toggleClass('cntnt');
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #4a4f55;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<div class="wrapper-content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn pull-left" id="menu-toggle" >
      toggle menu
    </a>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1>Simple Sidebar</h1>
        <p>This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens, the page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>
        <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hi, Im trying to Create a css class in jQuery & assigning it to another id in jQuery.
The main agenda is, I want to toggleClass a class in jQuery, which has a width of the $(window), on click on a function that class should be toggled to an id,

here's the code which I implemented, I've got no errors, but not output too.
Help me out please.

Comment: here's the fiddle code, in this to "wrapper-content" i would like to add the dynamic class "cntnt".
https://jsfiddle.net/zeasts/jmr3L9hp/4/

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('.cntnt').css('width', + windowwidth + 'px');
})
```

This is not class assignation, you just find elements with this class and set them style.

If you want to dynamically set class you should create new style element, something like:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('body').prepend('<style>.cntnt { width:' + windowwidth + 'px }</style>')
})
```

Comment: the browser is firing an error in console that "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list", what does this means ? @meler.

Comment: `$(window).load(function () {
    $('body').prepend('<style>.cntnt { width:' + windowwidth + 'px }</style>')
})`

Comment: yup it worked fine, I've basic knowledge in jQuery. Thanks @Meler

Answer (score 0):

In order to dynamically create a css class you can create a `<style>` element and append it to `<head>`.

```
$("<style>")
  .prop("type", "text/css")
  .html(".cntnt { width: " + windowwidth + "px; }")
  .appendTo("head");
```

Or, if you only need the *windowidth*, you can simply create a class in static css with `vw` and `calc`. Which `100vw` is equal to `$(window).width()` and `calc` calculate the value between different units. In this way you get the advantage of dynamically re-calculate the width whenever user resize the window. With javascript, you need to put your code inside `$(window).resize` event to do so.

```
.cntnt {
  width: calc(100vw - 50px);
}
```

Comment: you should point out which part is not working out so that we can help you, but I saw that you have it worked already, so... nvm.